# Multiple arctan in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried this in matlab :

```
a=2*pi*10^6;
b=6*pi*10^6;
c=20*pi*10^6;

solve ('atan(w/a) + atan(w/b) + atan(w/c) = 115')
```

want to find 'w' But I get the following error:

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
In solve at 83

ans =[ empty sym ]
```

Can someone help me with my matlab error?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution.

The maximum of `atan` is `pi/2`, the left side is between `3*pi/2` and `-3*pi/2`, it is never equal to 115.

Keep in mind that `atan` uses radians, not degrees.

Comment: This is on paper equation , how to find in matlab ? does not matter uses radians or degrees !

Comment: No solution = solution is an empty set. Exactly what solve returned.

Comment: oh now i got it , i had mistake with radians and degrees...thnks